# Need help parse error GNU Octave

Tags: linux, octave

I try writing the linear & nonlinear regression on GNU Octave as a part of my final project for Numerical Method class. Still I have one error in my code it's a simple parse error but I don't know how to fix it. I try to fix the syntax or try change the way I do my coding still stuck.

```
printf("This program is use for curve fitting\n")
printf("Please enter the data in the [] by use one space to seperate each element.\n")
x = input("Enter the data(x group):")
y = input("Enter the data(y group):")
mode = input("What kind of fitting you want to do(expo((1),power(2),least-square fitting(3)):")
switch mode
case{3}
    xbar = sum(x)/length(x) 
    ybar = sum(y)/length(y)
    xy = x.*y
    xs = x.^2
    a1 = ((length(x)*sum(xy))-(sum(x)*sum(y)))/((sum(xs)*length(x))-(sum(x)^2))
    a0 = ybar-(a1*xbar)
    disp(x)
    disp(y)
    printf("mean of x = %d,mean of y = %d,a1 = %d.a0 = %d",xbar,ybar,a1,a0)
    plot(a0+(a1*x))
case{2}
    xbar = sum(x)/length(x) 
    ybar = sum(y)/length(y)
    xy = x.*y
    xs = x.^2
    a1 = ((length(x)*sum(xy))-(sum(x)*sum(y)))/((sum(xs)*length(x))-(sum(x)^2))
    a0 = ybar-(a1*xbar)
    alpha = 10^a0
    disp(x)
    disp(y)
    printf("mean of x = %d,mean of y = %d,a1 = %d.a0 = %d,alpha = %d,beta = %d\n",xbar,ybar,a1,a0,alpha,a0)
    plot((alpha.*(x^a1))
case{1}
    xbar = sum(x)/length(x)
    ybar = sum(y)/length(y)
    xy= x.*y
    xs= x.^2
    a1 = ((length(x)*sum(xy))-(sum(x)*sum(y)))/((sum(xs)*length(x))-(sum(x)^2))
    a0 = ybar-(a1*xbar)
    disp(x)
    disp(y)
    alpha = e^a1
    printf("mean of x = %d,mean of y = %d,a1 = %d.a0 = %d,alpha = %d,beta = %d\n",xbar,ybar,a1,a0,alpha,a0)
    plot(a0*(e^((a1*alpha).*x))
otherwise
    break;
end
```

Parse error keep telling that the place where error occur is case{1} but I don't know what the error is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line before that case label has mismatched parentheses:

```
plot((alpha.*(x^a1))
```

Comment: Thanks this will make me finally finish my project